# fireEvent.click with parameters

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a radio button that when I click it calls a function with two parameters in the function (value and step), and when I make a test with testing librairy I would like that when I simulate the click of the button I return the two parameters.

**Button**

```
      <Form.Check
                inline
                label={'form.email'}
                name="media"
                value={`LETTER`}
                type="radio"
                data-testid="EMAIL"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  const target = e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement;
                  changeMedia(target.value, data);
                }}
               />
```

**Function ChangeMedia**

```
   const changeMedia = (value: any, step: any) => {
   step.definition?.steps
      .filter((obj: any) => obj.media.includes(value))
        .map((item: any) => {
     if (value === 'EMAIL') {
      item.media = 'LETTER';
      return item;
    } else if (value === 'LETTER') {
      item.media = 'EMAIL';
      return item;
    }
    return item;
  });
return data;
 };
```

**Objet Step**

```
   const step = {
  definition: {
      steps: [
      {
        document_model: 'template_circularization',
        email_model: 'email_circularization',
        label: {
          EN: 'Circularization',
          FR: 'Circularisation',
        },
        media: 'LETTER',
        name: 'mail_circularization',
        onDemandOnly: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  };
```

**Test**

```
const radio = screen.getByTestId('EMAIL');
fireEvent.click(radio, { target: { value: 'EMAIL, step: step } });
```

when I do a `console.log` of value and step I get this :

value EMAIL
step {}

what would be the solution to retrieve the `step` object via `firevent.click` ?

Comment: I would recommend trying to write your test based on what the user actually sees and not by what objects are returned. Testing implemention details will often make your tests less maintainble. What do you expect to see after you click on the radio button?